# Proving a convex function

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

I'm given a function  $f:A \to \mathbb{R}$ which is twice continuously differentiable on $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. $A$ is a convex set. Show that $f$ is convex.
Any ideas on how to prove this?

Comment: You can check the second derivative. If it is positive then the function is convex. However, do you know anything else about the function? Because being twice continuously differentiable does not mean it has to be convex.

Comment: I've given an upvote because the OP shouldn't loose rep for this. But yeah what have you thought about?

Comment: I added that $A$ is a convex set.

Comment: Use the extrema, sometimes it can help

Comment: $\sin x$ is infinitely differentiable on $A=\mathbf R$, which is a convex set, and is not convex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People have commented, but this deserves an answer.

Problem statement:  "I'm given a function $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ which is twice continuously differentiable on $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$. $A$ is a convex set. Show that $f$ is convex."

The statement is false as written. Consider the function $f(x) = -x * x$ , defined on the convex set $\mathbb{R}$. $f(x)$ is twice continuously differentiable on $A$, and indeed, continuously differentiable of all orders.  Yet, $f(x)$ is not convex.

The statement is false, as should be immediately and overwhelmingly apparent to anyone with any capability at all in mathematics.  Nevertheless, to be charitable, one can suppose the possibility of a "typo" in which some other condition was accidentally omitted from the problem statement.  The hypothesis would need to be strengthened in some way in order for the statement to become true, for instance, by adding the hypothesis that the Hessian of $f$ is positive semi-definite at every point in the domain $A$.

Edit: Proof of the statement, with the hypothesis added that the Hessian of $f$ is positive semi-definite at every point in the domain $A$, can be found in numerous textbooks.